# Unity activation from Command line

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to run not-activated Unity Personal Edition (no serial number) via Command Line? If I pass `username` and `password` it still asks to select type of License.

Comment: I also looked into this for a good handful of hours. There is a -force-free option, however this still will not override the activation process, it appears to only be for temporarily downgrading a commercial license.

There is another possibility, automating the 3-step 'manual activation', steps 1 and 3 are via the command line, you'd need some script to upload the ufl file to Unity license services for step 2.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, the only function of those parameters are to pre-fill uservame and password, but unity needs to be activated as well, otherwise the popup shows to proceed with the activation.

Comment: I also looked into this for a good handful of hours. There is a -force-free option, however this still will not override the activation process, it appears to only be for temporarily downgrading a commercial license.

There is another posibility, automating the manual activation'